# changing items in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I inserted/removing from particular position in ArrayList onBindViewHolder . Now , i want to show this modified list on recyclerview .

**Adapter Code:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyAdapterViewHolder> {
    private List<Info> dataList;
    private Context mAct;
    private List<Info> totalCandidatesList;
    private  String TAG = "OWD";

    public MyAdapter(List<Info> dataList, Context context) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mAct = context;
    }

    public void addApplications(List<Info> candidates) {

        if(this.totalCandidatesList == null){
            totalCandidatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.dataList.addAll(candidates);
        this.totalCandidatesList.addAll(candidates);
        this.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, candidates.size() - 1);

    }

    public void clearApplications() {
        int size = this.dataList.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                dataList.remove(0);
                totalCandidatesList.remove(0);
            }
            this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapterViewHolder mAdapterViewHolder, int i) {

        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            mAdapterViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ecf5fe"));
            mAdapterViewHolder.layoutRipple.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ecf5fe"));
        } else {
            mAdapterViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e2f1ff"));
            mAdapterViewHolder.layoutRipple.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e2f1ff"));
        }


        final WorkHolders workHolders = SingleTon.getInstance().getWorkHolders();
        final String customerName = SingleTon.getInstance().getCustomerName();
        String siteName = null;
        if(customerName !=null) {
            String[] sitenamearray = customerName.split("--");

            if (sitenamearray.length > 1) {
                siteName = sitenamearray[1];
            }
        }
        final Info ci = dataList.get(i);
        mAdapterViewHolder.title.setText(ci.heading1);
        mAdapterViewHolder.jobNumber.setText(ci.heading2);
        mAdapterViewHolder.distance.setText(ci.distance);

        if(siteName != null && siteName.equalsIgnoreCase(ci.heading2)) {
            mAdapterViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a7ffeb"));
            mAdapterViewHolder.layoutRipple.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a7ffeb"));
            if(i!=0){


>  //Here i removed and inserted item in list . 
>                     dataList.remove(i);
>                     dataList.add(0,ci);

            }
      }

        final String finalSiteName = siteName;
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        mAdapterViewHolder.layoutRipple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment;

                String name = ci.heading1 + "--" + ci.heading2;

                Log.d(TAG,"new Jobname : "+ name);
                if (finalSiteName == null || finalSiteName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                    bundle.putString("name", customerName);
                    bundle.putString("oldwork", "yes");
                    bundle.putString("running_job_selected", "yes");
                } else {

                    Log.d(TAG,"StartedOn Before Sending Bundle :" + workHolders.startedOn);
                    Log.d(TAG, "running Job is not selected");

                    bundle.putString("name", name);
                    bundle.putString("oldwork", "yes");
                    bundle.putString("running_job_selected", "no");
                }

                FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) mAct).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_in, R.anim.glide_fragment_horizontal_out);

                fragment = new WorkDescriptionFragment();

                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ft.addToBackStack("myadapter");
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                SingleTon.getInstance().setWorkStatus("start");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.single_item1, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyAdapterViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public static class MyAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView title;
        protected TextView dateTime;
        protected TextView distance;
        protected TextView jobNumber;

        protected CardView cardView;
        protected LayoutRipple layoutRipple;

        public MyAdapterViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            dateTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeTextView);
            distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);
            jobNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jobNumber);
            cardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            layoutRipple = (LayoutRipple)v.findViewById(R.id.singleitemripple);
        }
    }

}
```

you will see following lines in above code where i am removing/inserting item in a list onBindview and would like to show same in recyclerview .

> But right now i am getting normal datalist(unchanged) .

```
//Here i removed and inserted item in list . 
                      dataList.remove(i);
                      dataList.add(0,ci);
```

**Please help me to achieve this .**

Comment: please try to explain you problem more precisely. It is not clear what you are trying to achive.

Comment: @alexeypolusov : i want to change Adapter datalist item in onBindViewHolder method

Comment: why do you need to update data there? If you want to update data, just update the List inside you adapter and then nofifyDataChanged()

Comment: i am updating data if you could see the code . Even pasted the lines . but writing nofifyDataChanged()  in onBindViewHolder give me error :cannot "call this method while recyclerview is computing a layout or scrolling"

Comment: why do you need to update your adapter from onBindViewHolder? This is NOT the place where you should update you data

Comment: @alexeypolusov   Yes , i figured out the solution . Hence,i request you to write something as answer so that i can accept and close this question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onBindViewHolder is not the place where you should update your adapter. The staregy is to update item inside your Adapter data list and then notifyDataChanged(). For example thise are the methods for updating info inside my adapter:

```
    public void update(Track track) {
        tracks.remove(track);
        add(track);
    }

    public void add (Track track) {
        tracks.add(track);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addTracks(List<Track> tracks){
        this.tracks.addAll(tracks);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearAndAddTracks(List<Track> tracks) {

        for (int i = 0; i < this.tracks.size(); i++) {
            if (!this.tracks.get(i).isRunning()){

            }
        }
        this.tracks.clear();
        this.tracks.addAll(tracks);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . i changed my code according to your advice . Thank you . Also , i would be grateful if you upvote the question . Thanks again